# Numpy string scalar comparison

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, filter, comparison

I'm seeing a strange behavior with Numpy or I'm just bad at it.

I have a structured array with some string field. Now I want to filter the data based on that field. My understanding is that, this would work:

```
data['somefield'][data['filterfield'] == 'someconstant']
```

But strangely, it did not. I'm under assumption that

```
data['filterfield'] == 'someconstant'
```

Will produce an array of boolean. But it did not, it return a boolean (not an array of it). So instead of that, using

```
data['filterfield'] == full(data.shape,'someconstant',dtype=data['filterfield'].dtype)
```

works as expected but its a hassle and error prone. Is this an expected behavior? If so, is there a shorter way to create an array of string?

Comment: `data['filterfield'] == 'someconstant'` produce a boolean for sure, not an array! If you execute `data['somefield'][data['filterfield'] == 'someconstant']`, it will understand as like `data['somefield'][True]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data['filterfield']` probably is a list of strings.  `np.char` has a set of operations for this type of array.  It looks like the ordinary `array==scalar` test for numeric arrays does not work with this type of array. `np.char.equal(c1,c2)` compares two char arrays, and doesn't have a provision for one of those being a plain string.

So your approach, generating another string array, is the right one.  But it can be simpler (due to broadcasting):

```
In [326]: x=np.array([(1,'one'),(2,'two'),(3,'three')],dtype='int,S10')

In [327]: x['f1']
Out[327]: 
array([b'one', b'two', b'three'], 
      dtype='|S10')

In [328]: x['f1']==np.array('two',dtype='S')
Out[328]: array([False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

`np.array('two')` might also work if the default char type matches with `x`.  I did this testing in `python3`, so '

There may be other options using `np.char` functions, but this is straightforward and simple.

Comment: Yup, I thought so too. But I never knew np.array('two',stype='S') would work. I thought it would create an array of char.

Comment: In some contexts (`loadtxt`?) a simple `S` is taken to mean `S1`, 1 char.  But apparently in this use it chooses sufficient characters.